# Does OSX preview tool tag images with any kind of metadata or anything to identify the computer?

Tags: macos, mac, images

I have some images I want to post online which I am touching up with OSX preview app to resize them.  I however dont want my compiuter information such as my name, IP address, location or anything to be attached to the images as I really value my privacy.  Ive heard that Photoshop sometimes does attach your computer name to the images, so I want to avoid that.

Anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes softwares link photoshop do attach a lot of EXIF metadata to files.

You might check it using tools like [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (not provided by default, you can install it with MacPort).

Your only solution since almost every software adds some exif data is to using tools to delete these data.

[Jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) is another tool that allows you to change or delete the exif.